# Recursion increment clarify

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
      int v[]={0,1,1,1};
      int f(int x)
      {
          if(x>=1)  return v[x]+f(x-1);
          else return 0; 
      }
```

When I called it in main like so: `cout<<f(4);` It's outputting '4' but I expect to be '3'
Can someone clarify why I get '4' and not '3' ? (I think I'm missing something)

Comment: `v[4]` is undefined, indices are counted from 0 in C++

Comment: well `v[4]` doesn't exist, so who knows what you will get from that. I think the thing you are missing here is that indexes are zero based (start at 0) not starting with 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

v[4] is not defined. It has 4 elements, so the max array index is 3.

Answer (score 4):

Anything can happen because this is undefined behavior. **Arrays in C++ are 0-based - they start at 0 and go to number of elements - 1**.

`4` is a perfectly valid answer, as would `10` or `42` be.

`v` only has indexes `0...3`, anything other than that is UB.

Answer (score 2):

v[4] has 4 elements and hence max index is 3. The array index starts from 0 and since you have not initialized it it will take the max index as 3 as it has 4 elements at present.

Answer (score 0):

The output of

```
      int v[]={0,1,1,1};
      int f(int x)
      {
          if(x>=1)  return v[x]+f(x-1);
          else return 0; 
      }
```

is undefined when called with `cout << f(4)` because its getting the value beyond x=3. This is incorrect. Arrays start at 0 and for your array, its range is from 0 -> 3(=4 elements).

To correct it, you must call `cout << f(3);`

Also to check for the range:

A simple check like this inside `int f(x)` will give you the correct result.

Something like this:

```
  #define checkRange(x,y) (((sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])) >= y)?true:false)

  int v[]={0,1,1,1};
  int f(int x)
  {
      if(!checkRange(v,x)){
          return 0+f(x-1);
      }
      if(x>=1)  return v[x]+f(x-1);
      else return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: `int elementcount = (sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]));` No, that just doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: You seem to think that `sizeof(ptr)` returns size of allocated space that pointer points to, is that right?

Comment: in bytes? yes. Am I wrong? if so can you point to a location on the internet that can school me?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. `sizeof` operator returns a compile-time constant size of the *type*, in this case `int*`, which is typically 4 on 32-bit systems and 8 on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @jrok, I have compiled the program I have written. It gives me a correct output. sizeof() of an array returns the number of bytes allocated by that array. dividing it by the size of each element gives you the number of elements in the array. This is a standard construct to get the length of an array in c and c++

Comment: Arrays are not pointers (and vice versa). You have been warned :)

Comment: :) you're right. I used a function when I should have used a macro. EDITING!

Comment: @jrok what do you think of that now? :)